# Why is Python Selenium downloading 0 KB files?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to automate downloading files from a website for work. I have a while loop which will download the correct amount of files based on a query that the user enters. Some of the files being downloaded are 0 KB which is not correct. When they are manually downloaded they are not 0 KB. For some reason this is only happening with the xlsx files being downloaded and not the csv files.

How can I fix this? I don't want to add a long time.sleep() line because this code is supposed to save time and sometimes downloads thousands of files. Below is my relevant code.

```py
while i <= page_count:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[contains(text(),'Export')]")))
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[contains(text(),'Instant Export 1,000 Inline Transcript(s)')]")))
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)
    time.sleep(1)
    WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[*]/div/div/div/form/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/input"))).click()
    actions = ActionChains(driver)
    actions.send_keys(i)
    actions.perform()
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='modal-footer']//button[@class='btn btn-primary ng-binding']")))
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)
    time.sleep(1)
    download_wait(newpath, 60, i + existing_export_count)
    time.sleep(1)
    i += 1
```

Comment: I'm not sure how much we can do based only on a small code snippet, can you provide a [mcve]? As an aside, what is the point of a while loop which you increment by 1 for each iteration?

Comment: create code which we could run and test problem - and add real URL in code. Maybe only server has problem to send files in short time (especially if it doesn't send existing files but it has to generate them)

Comment: did you find an answer?