# Python and Selenium download 0 KB excel files

Tags: python, selenium

I have already been to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61150566/why-is-python-selenium-downloading-0-kb-files) with same question, but I cannot find an answer to it:
Although my question is the same as the other question, I posted a new one with my code as well.

```
url='https://example.com/'
download_url="https:/example.com/Download"
chromedriver = 'path\\to\chromedriver.exe'
options = Options()
    ua = UserAgent()
    userAgent = ua.random
    print(userAgent)
    options.add_argument(f'user-agent={userAgent}')
    options.add_experimental_option("prefs", {
        "download.default_directory": r"C:\Users\helia\Desktop\Test",
        "download.prompt_for_download": False,
        "download.directory_upgrade": True,
        "safebrowsing.enabled": True
    })
    options.add_argument("--headless")
    options.add_argument("--window-size=%s" % WINDOW_SIZE)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path=chromedriver)
 driver.get(url)
user_name = driver.find_element_by_name('User')
pass_word = driver.find_element_by_name("Pass")
user_name.send_keys("my_username")
pass_word.send_keys("my_password")
driver.find_element_by_class_name("btnn.btnn-default.b").click()
driver.get(download_url)
driver.find_element_by_class_name("btn.btn-app").click()
driver.switch_to.alert.accept()
```

The code successfully downloads the file but the file is 0 KB. both on the website and on my local; however, the file on the site has never been 0 before.
(the program finishes while the file is being downloaded, could it be the cause? do I need to add some waits?)

Comment: Did you try same in GUI mode ?

Comment: yes, the same also happens

Comment: Is it possible to share URL ? I would test in my local system, also since they are 0 byte file, I don't think so below answer is helpful. Cause how much time 0 bytes file takes to download ?

Comment: Also I read your other post, in which you mentioned that `I don't want to add a long time.sleep() line because this code is supposed to save time and sometimes downloads thousands of files.` for this you can check in downloaded folder if the file is present or not using python.

Comment: @cruisepandey the link is work-related not a public URL unfortunately :|
The point is that the file is removed from the source once downloaded once; however when I download it and it gets me 0kb, the source file still appears and it is in the size of 0 too.

Comment: Source means the server ? where files resides or is it a cloud ?

Comment: @cruisepandey it is a server from a 3rd party company but i don't know where it resides or is hosted

Comment: hmm.. still I did not get `file is removed from the source once downloaded`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not clear enough, however I guess your problem is:
After clicking the download button and accepting the alert your code finishes immediately so downloaded file have had no enough time to be actually downloaded.
In order to get the file completely downloaded you should prevent browser to be closed until the downloading not complete.

Comment: So adding some wait time would solve the issue? I thought it would continue downloading in the background

Comment: I think so. Downloading is done by browser. So when you closing the browser the downloading process is broken.